# How to make Oracle compare JSON as JSON, not as Strings

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I am struggling with querying a JSON column that contains data from an external system.

Consider the following test data:

```
create table foo  
(  
  foo_id integer primary key,   
  payload clob,   
  constraint ensure_json CHECK (payload IS JSON)  
);  
  
insert into foo values (1, '{"data": {"k1": 1, "k2": "foo"}, "ref": {"id": 1, "type": "type1"}}');  
insert into foo values (2, '{"data": {"k1": 2, "k2": "bar"}, "ref": {"type": "type1", "id":1}}');
```

I would like to check if the "ref" section contains the key/value pairs "id:1" and "type:type1"

The keys I want to compare are dynamic and the keys in the payload are dynamic as well (as I said an external source is providing that). So the following query:

```
select *  
from foo  
where json_query(payload, '$.ref') = '{"id":1,"type":"type1"}';
```

will only return the row with the primary foo_id = 1, but not the other row. Using JSON_OBJECT() instead of the string literal doesn't change anything.

I also tried: `json_query(payload, '$.ref') = json_object('id' value 1, 'type' value 'type1')` and `json_query(payload, '$.ref') = json_query('{"id":1,"type":"type1"}', '$')` but again only one row is found

According to the JSON RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159 ) the order of keys is irrelevant.

So the objects `{"id": 1, "type": "type1"}` and `{"type": "type1", "id": 1}` are the same and should be considered equal and the above query should return both rows (at least that's my understanding of the JSON rfc)

Essentially I am looking for a query that would behave like the following Postgres query (which returns both rows):

```
select *
from foo
where payload -> 'ref' = '{"id": 1, "type": "type1"}'::jsonb
```

<sup>assuming that `payload` is defined as `jsonb`</sup>

I know I can workaround this, using something like this:

```
select *  
from foo  
where json_value(payload, '$.ref.type') = 'type1'  
   and json_value(payload, '$.ref.id') = '1';
```

However that requires that the JSON object that is used to query the table has to be parsed and split into its elements. For a simple example like that this is somewhat acceptable but if the JSON is more complicated (or nested on multiple levels) this becomes a nightmare.

Is there any way I can tell Oracle to "normalize" the JSON object that is returned by `json_query(payload, '$.ref')` before comparing them?

Or even better: can I tell Oracle to compare them as real "objects" (=key/value pairs) rather the plain strings?

The ideal solution would be one where I can simply have a prepared statement in my Java code and could plug-in an arbitrary JSON as the parameter.

Currently I am testing this on Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 but it would be nice if there was a solution for 12.1 as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're lucky enough to upgrade to 18c, this is easy: use JSON_equal.

This is a new condition which does exactly what you're asking:

```
select *
from   foo
where  json_equal (
  '{"type": "type1", "id":1}',
  json_query(payload, '$.ref')
);

FOO_ID   PAYLOAD                                                               
       1 {"data": {"k1": 1, "k2": "foo"}, "ref": {"id": 1, "type": "type1"}}   
       2 {"data": {"k1": 2, "k2": "bar"}, "ref": {"type": "type1", "id":1}}
```

In the meantime, you'll have to go for something clunkier...

You could convert the JSON to a relational format using JSON_table:

```
select foo_id, id, type
from   foo, json_table (
  payload, '$' columns (
    nested path '$.ref[*]' columns (
      id path '$.id',
      type path '$.type'
    )
  )
);

FOO_ID   ID   TYPE    
       1 1    type1   
       2 1    type1
```

Then do the same with your comparison JSON. And use SQL set difference to compare them. Which is a bit of a faff...

Or on 12.2 you could use JSON_object to reconstruct the object with all the attributes in the same order:

```
with rws as (
  select foo_id, id, type
  from   foo, json_table (
    payload, '$' columns (
      nested path '$.ref[*]' columns (
        id path '$.id',
        type path '$.type'
      )
    )
  )
), j as (
  select foo_id, json_object (
           'id' value r.id, 'type' value r.type
         ) j
  from   rws r
)
  select * from j
  where  j.j = '{"id":"1","type":"type1"}';

FOO_ID   J                           
       1 {"id":"1","type":"type1"}   
       2 {"id":"1","type":"type1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to store the data as XML, not JSON. The reason why is that Oracle is "aware" of XML data and actually is able to interpret, manipulate and parse it correctly. It appears that Oracle's implementation of JSON isn't quite complete yet. It's simply stored as text and its syntax is validated through the check constraint, but the database kernel doesn't have the capability of actually understanding the data as it does with XML. This may change in a future version, but for now it's a drawback.

There are many helper functions out there nowadays when dealing with XML and JSON; for example APEX has a very useful write_json procedure in the APEX_JSON package which can take an XMLTYPE as a direct input to produce JSON from it.

There are also procedures to turn the JSON into XML, for example:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_json-package-generate-and-parse-json-documents-in-oracle#json-to-xml

Comment: Oracle Database 12.2 does have a feature to understand the structure of stored JSON: the [JSON Data Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/json-dataguide.html#GUID-219FC30E-89A7-4189-BC36-7B961A24067C)

Comment: Ah - interesting! I wasn't aware of that, thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

If the match literal

```
 '{"id":1,"type":"type1"}'
```

is *generated*, this simple workaround will work.

```
select 
foo.*  
from foo  
where json_query(payload, '$.ref') in ('{"id":1,"type":"type1"}','{"type":"type1","id":1}');
```